# Composable function not works correctly outside of main class in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am seeing very weird issue in `@Composable` function. I am collecting data in `flow`. When I tried the `@Composable` function inside the `activity`. It's working fine without any problem, but when I write outside the class it not working. I don't understand the problem.

1. **This code is working fine**

   ```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding by lazy { ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainActivityViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
                viewModel.showBottomSheetContent.collect {
                    binding.bottomSheetComposeView.setContent {
                        ModalBottomSheetSample()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        binding.buttonComposeView.setContent {
            ButtonViewContent()
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun ButtonViewContent() {
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    scope.launch {
                        viewModel.showBottomSheetContent.emit(true)
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Text(text = "Open Bottom Sheet")
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
    fun ModalBottomSheetSample() {
        val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden, skipHalfExpanded = true)
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        SideEffect {
            scope.launch {
                sheetState.show()
            }
        }
        ModalBottomSheetContent(sheetState)
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun ModalBottomSheetContent(sheetState: ModalBottomSheetState) {
        ModalBottomSheetLayout(
            sheetState = sheetState,
            sheetContent = {
                LazyColumn {
                    items(5) {
                        ListItem(
                            icon = {
                                Icon(
                                    Icons.Default.Favorite,
                                    contentDescription = null
                                )
                            },
                            text = { Text("Item $it") },
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        ) {}
    }
   }
   ```

**2. This code not works correctly**

```
package com.hub.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Favorite
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.SideEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle
import com.hub.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding by lazy { ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainActivityViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
                viewModel.showBottomSheetContent.collect {
                    binding.bottomSheetComposeView.setContent {
                        ModalBottomSheetSample()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        binding.buttonComposeView.setContent {
            ButtonViewContent()
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun ButtonViewContent() {
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    scope.launch {
                        viewModel.showBottomSheetContent.emit(true)
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Text(text = "Open Bottom Sheet")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
fun ModalBottomSheetSample() {
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden, skipHalfExpanded = true)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    SideEffect {
        scope.launch {
            sheetState.show()
        }
    }
    ModalBottomSheetContent(sheetState)
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun ModalBottomSheetContent(sheetState: ModalBottomSheetState) {
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = sheetState,
        sheetContent = {
            LazyColumn {
                items(5) {
                    ListItem(
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                Icons.Default.Favorite,
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
                        },
                        text = { Text("Item $it") },
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) {}
}
```